# QtCreator - back slashes in path prevents QT application from deploying to android

Tags: android, qt, deployment, build, qt-creator

I try to create qtquick extention and app which uses it. The project root folder is: f:/work/app-project.
There is all.pro file in that folder:

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs

SUBDIRS += \
    app \
    ext

ext.subdir         = ext
app.depends        = ext
```

When I try to build and deploy project to my android device, I have got an errors:

```
Starting: "D:\Qt\Tools\mingw482_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" INSTALL_ROOT="F:/work/app-project/build-app-Android_for_armeabi_GCC_4_8_Qt_5_3_1Debug/android-build" install
cd ext/ && ( test -e Makefile || D:/Qt/5.3/android_armv5/bin/qmake.exe F:/work/app-project/app/ext/ext.pro -spec android-g++ CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=declarative_debug CONFIG+=qml_debug -o Makefile ) && D:/Qt/Tools/mingw482_32/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile install
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'f:/work/app-project/build-app-Android_for_armeabi_GCC_4_8_Qt_5_3_1-Debug/ext'
/usr/bin/sh: D:MinGWmsys1.0workapp-projectbuild-app-Android_for_armeabi_GCC_4_8_Qt_5_3_1-Debugandroid-build/libs/armeabi/: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/sh: D:MinGWmsys1.0workapp-projectbuild-app-Android_for_armeabi_GCC_4_8_Qt_5_3_1-Debugandroid-build/libs/armeabi/: No such file or directory
```

It seems like path passed to MSYS contains MS slashes - '\', and MSYS simple eats it. How I can correct this?

Comment: Mh are you sure you have specified the path INSTALL_ROOT correctly? AFAIK the paths in cygwin are of the form /driveletter/dir, e.g., "/f/work".

Comment: Problem was that the MSYS was found by QMAKE and it's sh.exe used, which eats slashes. Removing MSYS from PATH solves problem. In addition, the `test` required, and I wrote `.bat` file for replacement